# Deleting a model instance: pattern for handling references in get()

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have several views is a Django project that handle deletion of model instances. Certain models have business logic that says "if the instance of the model has been referenced elsewhere then do not allow the user to delete it". This has been applied using `on_delete=models.PROTECT` on the foreign key of the referring model. Nothing out of the ordinary here.

Now to the delete view. Things work fine, the ProtectedError is caught in `post()` and all is well. However for UX reasons I want this caught in `get()` too---this saves a button click and page load.

What I have been doing to date is using `TransactionMiddleware` and deleting and rolling back in the get request. All is well:

```
class PackageTypeDeleteView(DeleteView):
    ...

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Check for protected error
        """
        self.object = self.get_object()
        context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
        try:
            self.object.delete()
            transaction.rollback()
            return self.render_to_response(context)
        except ProtectedError:
            context = self.get_context_data()
            context['error'] = (
                'This package type has been used. ' +
                'Edit the package type and change Active to False.')
            context['object'] = self.object
        transaction.rollback()
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

However with `TransactionMiddleware` deprecated in 1.6 (I'm on 1.7), I'm removing it. I have not been able to find a way to implement the above functionality. As per [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic) I've tried decorating the method in `@transaction.atomic`, but obviously the problem for me is that I want the transaction rolled back *regardless*.

The first question is how do I replicate the functionality I had using the deprecated `TransactionMiddleware`?
But stepping back from the problem a little, the second question is am I using the right design pattern here? Does a robust pattern already exist that I haven't found?

Thanks
Nathan

Comment: _"However for UX reasons I want this caught in get() too---this saves a button click and page load."_ - care to elaborate what do you mean by this?

Comment: The out of the box pattern is: visit delete view via GET and and the user is given a confirmation screen. Submit the form and that POSTs where the ProtectedError is handled. The problem from the user's perspective is why should they have to go through the GET to be told that they can't delete the instance? There is an opportunity in get() to give them feedback there and then.